# MS Word - fomat a Content Control with bullet points

Tags: ms-word, bulletedlist, word-contentcontrol

I'm working with Content Controls in MS Word 2010. I add text to the Content Controls using Java. Some of the text contains several sentences and I would like to see each sentence appear as a bullet point. I've managed to define a bullet point style in MS Word. However, I don't know how to make each sentence appear as a bullet point (now the entire text appears as just one bullet point). What is the best way of going about this? I'm considering using VBA but am not sure how to add a VBA macro to a Content Control.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Could you post your code?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution and would not recommend using docx4j if you can find any better option.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, bullet points are implemented via list numbering.

For list numbering, you need paragraphs (you set the numPr on the pPr).

For a content control to contain paragraphs, you need a block level content control.

So, you need a block level rich text content control, then put your content in it, one paragraph per sentence, formatted using your list numbering (either directly applying the numPr, or a style which uses that numPr).

Comment: You can generate code from a sample docx using the docx4j webapp, or the Helper Word AddIn